# DHCP Authorization for Non-Windows Devices

Tags: windows, dhcp-server

I hope I can nail this question because I keep having a difficult time framing it properly.

I'm looking at the feasibility of configuring switches to act as a DHCP server. In this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781697(v=ws.10).aspx it defines how **stand-alone servers** work but was wondering if all noted behavior extends to any non-Windows device acting as a DHCP server or if the noted behavior is specifically for Windows OS.

Has anyone used a non-Windows DHCP server in an AD environment?
Was authorization required with the device IP and/or name?
Were there any other requirements?

Thanks!

/m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any non-Windows device can be a DHCP server and "Authorization" does not apply.  The "Authorization" feature is only a safety feature of a Windows DHCP server IF it is a Windows domain member, or a standalone Windows DHCP server that detects other DHCP servers on the network.

Comment: To answers  exacly to the question and to improve Greg reply yes you can use a non windows DHCP in active directory "network" . To contact an AD , windows clients needs to resolvs DNS record about AD (rolename records) . To be short : Yes you can use dhcp server not on windows , you just have to get the right IP config and the right DNS in this DHCP .

Comment: Greg, I presumed it was as you stated but wanted some validation for clarity. Thanks very much!